# Questions about share memory in the tree reduction

Tags: cuda

On page 22 of NVIDIA [Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf),

```
__device__ void warpReduce(volatile int* sdata, int tid) {
sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8];
sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4];
sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2];
sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];
}

// later…
for (unsigned int s=blockDim.x/2; s>32; s>>=1) {
if (tid < s)
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
__syncthreads();
}
if (tid < 32) warpReduce(sdata, tid);
```

I am not sure how CUDA processes the operation in the last line of the function `warpReduce(...)`: `sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];`. If a warp has thread ID `tid` from 0 to 31, does `tid` 0 and 1 conflict at thie moment? What I mean is, how will CUDA choose the order of `sdata[0] += sdata[0 + 1];` and `sdata[1] += sdata[1 + 1];`? If it runs `sdata[0] += sdata[0 + 1];` first, then the result is correct. Or, CUDA do something to prevent this confusion/conflicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those slides are horribly outdated. Using shared memory for reductions within a single warp hasn't been state-of-the-art since warp shuffle instructions were invented in CUDA-3.0 (IIRC). And even those are obsolete at this point.

These days you would use the [warp reduce functions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-reduce-functions) such as `__reduce_add_sync`.

As for why the pattern above used to work: Prior to the Volta architecture, threads in a warp operated in lockstep. They would all first load the value, then store it. Therefore synchronization was unnecessary. This has changed. Note this from Nvidia's [Volta Tuning Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/volta-tuning-guide/index.html)

> Applications that assume reads and writes are implicitly visible to other threads in the same warp need to insert the new __syncwarp() warp-wide barrier synchronization instruction between steps where data is exchanged between threads via global or shared memory. Assumptions that code is executed in lockstep or that reads/writes from separate threads are visible across a warp without synchronization are invalid.

You may find newer sample code in the Github repository: https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples

There may also be a newer version of those slides out there but I don't know where.